# Force Entity Framework to generate SQL query with DateTime in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got a query that generates no results when executed via entity framework, but the generated  SQL produces 1 result

Here's the EF query

```
    var fd = fromdate.ToUniversalTime();
    var td = todate.ToUniversalTime();

   var schedulesToSelect = db.SP_Schedule.Where(s => s.SP_ActiveSchedule.Active 
                           && channelIds.Contains(s.ChannelID)
                           && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.ScheduleTXDateTimeStart) >= fd               
                           && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.ScheduleTXDateTimeStart) < td)
                         .Select(s => s.ScheduleID).ToList();
```

When I run the SQLgenerated via   `db.Database.Log =  s=> Debug.Write(s);` in SSMS

which results in this

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ScheduleID] AS [ScheduleID]
FROM  [dbo].[SP_Schedule] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SP_ActiveSchedule] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ScheduleID] = [Extent2].[ScheduleID]
WHERE ([Extent1].[ChannelID] IN (25)) AND ([Extent2].[Active] = 1)
AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[ScheduleTXDateTimeStart], 102) ,  102)) >= @p__linq__0) 
AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[ScheduleTXDateTimeStart], 102) ,  102)) < @p__linq__1)
-- p__linq__0: '04/04/2015 23:00:00' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)
-- p__linq__1: '05/04/2015 23:00:00' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)
```

I get 1 result.

The current thread culture is `en-GB', SQL server culture is us_english. I get that it's a DateTime issue, but how do i force EF to generate a SQL query with date times in the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format?

Comment: Have you considered changing the culture info of the current thread?

Comment: Reluctantly yes, but all my users are in the UK. I sadly don't have any control over the language of the database.

Comment: It just seems that being able to tell EF what format of date to generate is something that should be available?

Comment: Or more to the point that EF by default SHOULD use the 'yyyy-MM-dd' date format.

Comment: what's the column type for `ScheduleTXDateTimeStart`?

Comment: Datetime or datetime2

Comment: In any case I've just changed the thread culture to US and made sure all the dates that are being sent from client to server are in ISO 8601. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of problem a number of times when dealing with internationalization.

What I usually do is rewrite my LINQ queries like such:

```
DB.somerecords.Where(x=>x.Date.Year == DateParameter.Year 
                     && x.Date.Month == DateParameter.Month 
                     && x.Date.Day == DateParameter.Day)
```

or alternatively

```
from res in DB.somerecords where x.Date.Year == DateParameter.Year 
                              && x.Date.Month == DateParameter.Month 
                              && x.Date.Day == DateParameter.Day
select res
```

There is slightly more overhead associated with the three separate comparisons, but it's hardly noticeable.

On the plus side, it's a much more flexible way of filtering dates because you can compare only year, month, day, hour, minute, second or any combination of the above.

You may also find the following method helpful:

```
DB.ExecuteQuery<TResult>(string query, params object[] parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you, But that logic is going to get pretty nasty when dealing with BETWEEN queries. ie: comparing between '2015-05-06' AND '2015-06-05'